# Put hl-line last in the stack of Emacs backgrounds

Tags: emacs, colors, background, highlight, highlighting

How can we configure (or fix?) hl-line so that its background highlight goes last (or first?) in the stack.

That is: if hl-line highlights one line where some words are already having a background color, hl-line should NOT override that background color with its own.

It should go in the back, letting other background colors to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use library [`hl-line+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-line%2b.el) (see also [highlight current line](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentLine)) then you can set the priority of the overlay used by hl-line. To do what you want, you can reduce the number below that used by other overlays.

(You can even use a negative number, but that is undocumented -- see Emacs [bug #16192](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16192). And you can use a cons cell with a main priority and a secondary priority -- see bug [#17234](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17234).)

**However, overlay highlighting always takes priority over text-property highlighting.** So you cannot make an overlay appear to be "under" some text-property highlighting.

Comment: I'm stuck then, as my main use case is for Org TODO keywords, and words highlighted via M-x highlight-symbol-at-point, and both seem to be text properties... Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: It seems that a workaround could be a hl-line package written with text properties?  Or even not enough?

Comment: For symbol highlighting, see [this answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/23965/105): just use command **`hlt-highlight-symbol`** in library [**`highlight.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el), not `highlight-symbol-at-point`.

Comment: Thanks. However, it seems to me that the real patch would be to fix hl-line. Otherwise, every other package will have to be replaced or patched, as the highlight symbol stuff. But others will need to be patched: Org mode for its TODO keywords, every prog mode with language keywords having a background, etc.

Comment: You are welcome to submit a bug report to Emacs, to request what you want: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, either as an enhancement request or as a bug fix, if you think there is a bug. And if you attach a patch with the bug report, so much the better.

Comment: But do you think it's technically feasible to write an hl-line using text properties?

Comment: Sure it is technically feasible. But probably not a good idea. Temporarily highlighting buffer positions, as opposed to highlighting the underlying text, is what overlays are *for*. And making given highlighting use overlays vs text properties should generally not be a solution to someone's choice of which should appear to be on top. One issue is that we tend to think of highlighting a buffer region with a *background* as putting such a background *behind* or *underneath* the text. Think of a marker pen (highlighter) instead: the highlighting goes on top.